# is.numeric and is.numeric option in apply showing different result

Tags: r

I have a dataset which contain some 200 fields and 1000000 of records as per below format:

```
Acc Field1 Field2 Field3 .....    
101   23   34   78    
102   6    1.2  89    
.
.
.
```

When I enter command

```
apply(dat3[varlist[9]],2,is.numeric)
```

I get confirmation of field name with TRUE as a result, but when I try to test as `is.numeric(dat3[varlist[9]])`, I receive a FALSE as a result.

where dat3 is the dataframe on which I am working on and varlist is created using command:

```
varlist <- names(dat3)
```

varlist contains all the list of variables in the data frame.

Attached is the real time screenshot.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong over here.

Any help from anybody is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
varlist <- names(iris)
iris[varlist[1]]
```

you are defining a new dataframe with the selected column and not the variable itself.

do

```
iris[,colnames(iris) %in% varlist[1]]
is.numeric( iris[,colnames(iris) %in% varlist[1]])
#[1] TRUE
```

And try to make a reproducible example next time please

Comment: `iris[varlist[1]]` and `iris[,colnames(iris) %in% varlist[1]]
` are rather perverse indexing.  Just use `iris[, 1]` or `iris[[1]]`.

Comment: No problem. You can use datasets like `iris` and `mtcars` that are already available in R (or other ones, run `data()` to see a list of available datasets). Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @Richie I know, but I just wanted to start from his approach to show the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to perform tests column by column on a data frame is to use `sapply`.

```
sapply(mtcars, is.numeric)
sapply(CO2, is.numeric)
```

(Try swapping `is.numeric` for `class` as well.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `[` on a data.frame in this way will return another (smaller data frame). You need to use `[[`, or use the multi-index version of `[` so that dropping is applied. For example:

```
class(mtcars[3])
[1] "data.frame"
is.numeric(mtcars[3])
[1] FALSE
is.numeric(mtcars[[3]])
[1] TRUE
is.numeric(mtcars[,3])
[1] TRUE
```